# Angularfire2 Module has no exported member 'InjectionToken'

Tags: angularfire2

[Picture 1(Error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNSp7.png)

[Picture 2(My current Version)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkeLQ.png)

I have been developed an application by using ionic2 and now I am trying to connect my application with the database which I decide to use firebase. 
When I run my application it show an error as in the picture number 1

Comment: `InjectionToken` was introduced in Angular 4.